# Gephi not showing neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, gephi

I have create a relation betweeen node(0) and node(1) in neo4j. When i am viewing it in gephi, it is not showing anything on graph screen. 
In right most window pane it is showing nodes:2 and edges:0.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: how did you create it? could you paste the code?

Comment: I create node using cypher(web interface). Create node = {name:'amit'} then relation start a=node(0) , b=node(1) create a-[:knows]->b. Then I load it in gephi. It display nodes=2 edges=0 and even graph is not being displayed on screen. Neo4j interface display it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

May be I got the answer. Actually gephi does work only with neo4j 1.5 version but i was using 1.9 version.
After installing neo4j1.5 , it works. 
But now i shifted to neoclipse. It serve my purpose.